# ant design alert position in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I use alert of antd in react  and when I do the action for showing this alert, this alert will show in top of the website but I don't want to scroll to top of the site to see the alert and I want to see the alert in top position of where I am!
do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem with applying this style on alert :
style={{textAlign: 'right', direction: 'rtl' , position: 'fixed', width:'100%', zIndex:'100'}}

actually the position:'fixed' solved my problem!